# How to get the coordinates of points within an image?

Tags: plotting, graphics, programming, image-processing, image

How can I get the coordinates of an image, and make *Mathematica* draw the image from the coordinates found?  I am interested in just the outlines of the regions.

Here is an example of the kinds of images I'd like to process.
[image]

Comment: Coordinates refer to a *point*; your image is made up of a bunch of points. Now, which?

Comment: Is the skeleton you are looking for a cube with an S-shape on one of its sides?

Comment: Oh, you want the *outline*…

Comment: You mean EdgeDetect?

Comment: If you look closely, there is a "W" and "S", that need

Comment: Please clarify how what you want differs from the result of `EdgeDetect`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on your figure.  Then a set of graphics tools will appear beneath your figure.  Use the `Coordinates Tool`.  One by one, click on the corners of the region you seek.  Then use the window below to `Copy Coordinates`.  Here the ones I get for the front W face of your figure:

```
{{72.5`, 507.5`}, {70.5`, 158.5`}, {135.5`, 140.5`}, {136.5`, 
  484.5`}, {209.5`, 459.5`}, {208.5`, 120.5`}, {280.5`, 
  98.5`}, {282.5`, 437.5`}, {350.5`, 425.5`}, {347.5`, 7.5`}, {6.5`, 
  108.5`}, {7.5`, 530.5`}, {72.5`, 507.5`}}
```

Then merely plot them:

```
Graphics[{Blue, 
  Polygon@{{72.5`, 507.5`}, {70.5`, 158.5`}, {135.5`, 
     140.5`}, {136.5`, 484.5`}, {209.5`, 459.5`}, {208.5`, 
     120.5`}, {280.5`, 98.5`}, {282.5`, 437.5`}, {350.5`, 
     425.5`}, {347.5`, 7.5`}, {6.5`, 108.5`}, {7.5`, 530.5`}, {72.5`, 
     507.5`}}}]
```

[image]

Of course, you can repeat this for each face of your figure, for instance with the S:

[image]

If you just want the "skeleton" our outline, use `Line` instead of `Polygon`:

[image]

Comment: yes, I needed something like this, thanks

Comment: Sorry, do not leave me the coordinates of WS, the you can write please

Comment: @juanmunoz  Sorry, but I explained precisely how you could capture the points, gave you the points for the W, and I'm too busy to do more work for you.

Comment: sorry to bother, but nobody is born knowing, it may seem easy for some, but for others it is not so, just thanks for your help.

Comment: @juanmunoz Did you try to follow my explanation and directions in my solution?  If so, where did you have problems?

Comment: The idea got clear but incomplete figures leave me, I tried to make a closed path but always missing one hand, by making the two letters both left me open in some lado.He erased many times I've done.I do not do that bad.

Comment: Once you've copied n-1 points, then merely copy the *text* version of your *first* or starting point and paste it into our list so it is repeated as the *last* item.

Comment: With your last explanation I found it, thank you.
A little doubt.
  Does that feature the "@"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, Are you going to Caltech 8/10?

Comment: @alancalvitti Unlikely I'll go to Caltech.  Why do you ask?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, I emailed you through your site.